# Visual studio forms designer and derived usercontrols

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, designer

I have visual studio 2015 and code in C#. I use the windows forms designer and have:

1. class BaseControl
   with a tablelayout and some base controls + a (public) and in designer placed panel A to be filled by subcontrols
2. class SpecificControl : BaseControl
   if i open it in designer, i see (of course) all controls of the BaseControl. But i cannot place anything inside the panel A - even if A is public.

I see a small black rectangle in upper left corner of the panel (like blocked) and if a move e.g. a textbox onto the panel i see the circle with the line that shows me it is not allowed.

of course i can add my textbox by code cause panel A is public.

How can i make this working?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Modifiers` property of Panel A on `BaseControl` to `protected`

May also need to build project before it correctly picks this up.

Though I would say be careful using visual form inheritance in c#;  it can often cause more issues than it solves.

Comment: As I said, visual form inheritance doesn't seem to work as well as you'd like.  You may need to build the project and/or open/close the new form if you've changed the accessiblilty level of any elements after creating the new derived form.  I just tried this myself and was able to get it to do similar weird things but after building and opening/closing the new form I was able to use it as you'd expect.